# How to order column names that are strings in a bar graph in matplot lib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is an example of some of my data:

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame({"Experience":['8 to 9 years', '12 to 13 years', '13 to 14 years', '17 to 18 years',
                 '5 to 6 years', '19 to 20 years', '20 or more years', '14 to 15 years', '3 to 4 years',
                 '10 to 11 years', 'Less than a year', '4 to 5 years', '6 to 7 years',
                 '2 to 3 years', '15 to 16 years', '11 to 12 years', '16 to 17 years', '18 to 19 years',
                 '1 to 2 years', '9 to 10 years', '7 to 8 years', '8 to 9 years',
                 '12 to 13 years', '13 to 14 years', '14 to 15 years', '3 to 4 years',
                 '17 to 18 years', '5 to 6 years', '19 to 20 years', '20 or more years',
                 '10 to 11 years', 'Less than a year', '4 to 5 years', '6 to 7 years',
                 '2 to 3 years', '15 to 16 years', '11 to 12 years', '16 to 17 years',
                 '18 to 19 years', '1 to 2 years', '9 to 10 years', '7 to 8 years'],
               "Salary":[50000, 20000, 80000, 60000, 70000, 50000, 45000, 47000, 36000, 74000, 50000, 20000, 80000, 
                         60000, 70000, 50000, 45000, 47000, 36000, 74000, 90000, 50000, 20000, 80000, 60000, 70000, 
                         50000, 45000, 47000, 36000, 74000, 50000, 20000, 80000, 60000, 70000, 50000, 45000, 60000, 
                         70000, 50000, 45000]})
df

df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].astype('int64')
```

And this is the bar chart I made to compare the median salaries of each experience level:

```
from numpy import median
%matplotlib inline
group = df.groupby('Experience')
group.aggregate(median).plot(kind='barh')
```

Which gives me this graph:

[image: graph]

I would like the column names of the bar chart to be in order (eg. 'Less than a year', '1 to 2 years' etc), but I am struggling. What is the cleanest way for a beginner to pandas to do this?

Comment: Welcome, new coder! This is clearly written, but not quite a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have an idea for a workaround, but please write up an example that works end-to-end, e.g., has all the imports and some sample data in it. Include at least one case of "Less than a year" and something from each decade, as a thorough test.

Comment: @cphlewis Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I hope that the edited question is more in line with the requirements of the community. If you think you have an answer, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches, the first easy and automatic, the second sorting by one system and labelling with another.

The original problem is that the barplot, given text strings in "Experience", is sorting them alphabetically. We want a numerical order. A quick way is to extract numbers from the strings (with the function `to_min_number`) and group/plot that instead, editing the axis labels so the graph is still self-explanatory.

```
from pandas import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
df = DataFrame({"Experience":['8 to 9 years', '12 to 13 years', '13 to 14 years', '17 to 18 years',
                 '5 to 6 years', '19 to 20 years', '20 or more years', '14 to 15 years', '3 to 4 years',
                 '10 to 11 years', 'Less than a year', '4 to 5 years', '6 to 7 years',
                 '2 to 3 years', '15 to 16 years', '11 to 12 years', '16 to 17 years', '18 to 19 years',
                 '1 to 2 years', '9 to 10 years', '7 to 8 years', '8 to 9 years',
                 '12 to 13 years', '13 to 14 years', '14 to 15 years', '3 to 4 years',
                 '17 to 18 years', '5 to 6 years', '19 to 20 years', '20 or more years',
                 '10 to 11 years', 'Less than a year', '4 to 5 years', '6 to 7 years',
                 '2 to 3 years', '15 to 16 years', '11 to 12 years', '16 to 17 years',
                 '18 to 19 years', '1 to 2 years', '9 to 10 years', '7 to 8 years'],
               "Salary":[50000, 20000, 80000, 60000, 70000, 50000, 45000, 47000, 36000, 74000, 50000, 20000, 80000, 
                         60000, 70000, 50000, 45000, 47000, 36000, 74000, 90000, 50000, 20000, 80000, 60000, 70000, 
                         50000, 45000, 47000, 36000, 74000, 50000, 20000, 80000, 60000, 70000, 50000, 45000, 60000, 
                         70000, 50000, 45000]})
df

df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].astype('int64')

# Making a new column of Experience values that will plot gracefully
def to_min_number(experience):
    t = experience.split(' ')[0]
    if t == 'Less': return 0
    return int(t)

df['Minimum experience'] = map(to_min_number, df['Experience'])

from numpy import median
group = df.groupby('Minimum experience')
barplot = group.aggregate(median).plot(kind='barh', legend=None)
barplot.set_ylabel('Minimum years experience, non-overlapping')
barplot.set_xlabel('Salary, USD')
show()
```

[image]

If you have to have the original text strings, you can change the text of the y-tick-labels back according to the value in the `Minimum experience` column. The automatic `pandas` plotting only makes room for the numeric labels, so we force more room in the left margin of the axes we're plotting into:

```
# We are overriding the barplot defaults, so enforcing a new axis layout
fig, ax = subplots()
subplots_adjust(left=0.3)  # Argument is proportion of figure width; found by trial-and-error

barplot = group.aggregate(median).plot(ax=ax, kind='barh', legend=None) # pass it the ax
barplot.set_ylabel('Experience')
barplot.set_xlabel('Salary, USD')

# Need a list of new tick labels in lower-to-upper order. Use the group object, since we have it:
labellist = []
for i, v in group:
    labellist.append({'I':int(i), 'T':v.Experience.values[0]})
labeldf = DataFrame(labellist)

barplot.set_yticklabels(labeldf.sort_values(by='I')['T'])


show()
```

[image]

Note that, if the original text strings are not generated by a program with limited choices, you should put in more checks for variants: what if someone wrote "Up to 1 year"? "More than 20 years"?